# Getting the exact number of minutes of a given date

Tags: php, datetime, dst

Normally, there are 1440 minutes (60 min/hr * 24 hrs) on a normal day.  However, due to Daylight Savings Time, there can either 1380 minutes (60 min/hr * 23 hrs) or 1500 minutes (60 min/hr * 25 hrs).

How can find the exact number of minutes on a given date when provided with a a php's DateTime object?

For example, on March 13, 2016, DST starts in the US (and thus is a 23 hour day) and on November 6, 2016, DST ends in the US (and thus is a 25 hour day).  May 1, 2016 is a normal, 24 hour day.  I would like to have a function that would return the following:

```
$lomg= new DateTime('November 6, 2016T07:23:11');
$short= new DateTime('March 13, 2016T19:17:53');
$regular = new DateTime('May 1, 2016T22:45:00');

getMinutes($short); // Returns 1380
getMinutes($long); // Returns 1500
getMinutes($regular); // Returns 1440
```

Comment: Well stop using unix timestamps if you can avoid them, because they're all based on UTC; and start using DateTime objects which actually are timezone aware

Comment: Is DST currently in effect is possible to know using **`(bool)$dateTimeObject->format('I')`**.

Comment: The unix timestamp does not contain any timezone data. It is UTC and has no DST settings.

You should convert the time (e.g. with the DateTime() and DateTimeZone() classes in php) internally to the correct timezone and it will automatically adjust for DST and timezone offset based on the date.

Comment: `DST starts in the US (and thus is a 25 hour day)` - erm, no, its a 23 hour day: `print (strtotime('14 March 2016')-strtotime('13 March 2016'))/3600` (after setting your timezone correctly). And you are confusing datums and intervals.

Comment: You are all correct, and I botched my original question.  I am indeed working with a DateTime object and not a timestamp.  I edited my question accordingly. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @symcbean Ugh.  I botched that up as well.  Apologies.  I edited my question (again).

Comment: FYI - It's not just 23, 24, or 25.  On `Australia/Lord_Howe`, you'll find their DST bias is only 30 minutes, so they will have 23.5 or 24.5 hour DST transition days.  If you look into the past, you'll also find this in other time zones, and when standard offsets have been altered, such as the day that Venezuela moved from UTC-4:30 to UTC-4:00 earlier this year.

Answer (score 0):

The following should (in principle) work:

```
<?php


$dt = new DateTime();    
$dt->setTimestamp(1457827200);    
$dt->modify("today"); //Set to 00:00:00
$dt2 = clone $dt;     // Copy to new instance
$dt2->modify("+1 day");

var_dump(($dt2->getTimestamp() - $dt->getTimestamp())/60);
```

(Full disclaimer, did not test it)